# How can a Ruby script detect if it was triggered by an interactive shell?

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a Ruby script that is often kicked off as a cron job, but sometimes used from the command line.  I'd like to display some update text that is only relevant in the latter case, to show progress, and is not worth logging.

What is a safe and idiomatic way for a Ruby script to detect the following conditions?

- whether it was triggered in an interactive shell
- whether it is being piped

Comment: Really unfortunate that the other question didn't appear in the "Similar Questions" list ‍♂️.  The Stack Overflow owners are relying on volunteer labor to find duplicates that could be found by a half-decent search engine.

Comment: I would delete it, since it is legitimately a duplicate, but when I click the "Delete question" button SO posts a warning that you can be punished for deleting questions but gives no details ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if STDIN is a "TTY" (literally meaning [teletypewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter)) with [`IO#isatty`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-isatty).

```
$ ruby -e 'puts STDIN.isatty'
true
$ echo "no" | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.isatty'
false
```